# CKEditor jquery remote validation error not shown

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, ckeditor

The following is form containing the ckeditor on the field name = 'content':

```
<form id = "t_form">

    <div class="container">
            <label> Enter the content here: <label/><br>
            <?php echo form_textarea(array('name' =>'content','id'=>'content','class'=>"ckeditor form-control")); ?>
            <button class="btn-info btn submit"> Save </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The following is the corresponding jquery validate plugin call on the above form:

```
$("#t_form").validate({ignore: [],
    rules: 
    {
        content:{required: function() 
                    {
                         CKEDITOR.instances.content.updateElement();
                    },
        remote: {
            url: "http://localhost/karthi/my_site_t/t_save",
            async:false,
            type: "post"
            }
        }
    },
    messages: 
    {
        content:
        {
            required: "This field is required",
            remote: "Couldnt save for now! Try again!"
        }
    },

    submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!") }
});
```

In the t_save(), I return FALSE. Yet the error message: :"Couldnt save for now! Try again!" is not shown. Why is that?. But, "This field is required" error is shown, when submitted empty form.

Answer (score 0):

Using echo json_encode(FALSE) to return from the method: t_save(), solved my problem. Now I am able to get the error as "Couldnt save for now! Try again!".